# jQuery - validate form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I tried this code but it still submit the form even the input has not been validated yet.

Here is the code for my form:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" id="upload_image">Upload Image</a></li>

<?php
 $attributes = array('id' => 'upload_form'); 
 echo form_open_multipart('c=web_page&m=upload_img', $attributes); 
?>

<input type='file' style="display:none;" name="photosubmit" id="photosubmit"/>
<?php echo form_cose(); ?>
```

Here is the code for my jQuery:

```
$("#upload_image").click(function(){
 $("#photosubmit").click();
  if( $('photosubmit').val() != "") //
   $("#upload_form").submit();
});
```

so here is my question:

How will I ensure that before I submit this form, my input has already a value..?

Comment: <?php
 $attributes = array('id' => 'upload_form'); 
 echo form_open_multipart('c=web_page&m=upload_img', $attributes); 
?>

Comment: that one is the form element, I use codeigniter as my web app framework.

Comment: Your form, however you render it, needs a `onsubmit="return false;"`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission

Comment: but once i set it to return false, it won't submit the form.

Comment: Zhul, look at the updated solution. I am sure, it will work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day of research, I tried this one and it works. 
It will only submit the form once you have made any changes to the file input type form(e.g you want to upload new file).

```
$("#upload_image").click(function () {
  $("#photosubmit").click().change(function(){
    $("#upload_form").submit();
  });
});
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the element by id you should do this:

```
if( $('#photosubmit').val() != "")
```

instead of:

```
if( $('photosubmit').val() != "")
```

**Updated answer:**
With help of the [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/), I found a fully working solution:

```
$("#the_form").submit(function(event) {
  if ( $( "input:first" ).val() !== "" ) {
    alert("The file input is valid.");
    return;
  }
  alert("The file input is not valid.")
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/christianheinrichs/nbuzoxLv/2/

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: nothing, it just submit the form, without ensuring that the input has must a value first.

Comment: The problem may be somewhere else: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Jpg/) jsFiddle out. It submits the form, no matter if a file was selected or not. I am still trying to figure this out.

Comment: It's in my answer. Click the jsFiddle link.

Comment: i don't get it man, still not working. there's nothing happen in my browser. do we really need to have submit button to submit this form?

Comment: I think yes. You will need a submit button. It should work only when you click on it and don't select anything. Kinda buggy. But I hope there is some solution I can find.

Comment: I am trying something with event.preventDefault. Still a bit a tricky in this case.

Comment: yeah, i hope so.. if this the only solution i have.. i think i have to put a submit button in my page.

Comment: I really don't know. I tried every possible approach, but it does not check the file input field initially. Only after clicking on it and not giving a file to it.

Comment: yeah that's right, i'm also trying to figure it out, but it always give me the same results...

Comment: i think the file input has already a value before it is clicke

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#upload_image").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#photosubmit").val() != "") 
           ^ //added # here
    $("#upload_form").submit();
});
```

References

[event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: still not working man, aside from .val() function, is there any other method that i can use to ensure that my input file has been set?

Comment: i think the file input has already a value before it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is returned:

```
$("#photosubmit").val()
```

If returns `null` that is different from empty string.

Try this:

```
if ($("#photosubmit").val()) {
    $("#upload_form").submit();
}
```

Comment: still not working, it still submit the form even the file was selected or not

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an # in your code, it has to be:

```
$("#upload_image").click(function(){
 $("#photosubmit").click();
  if( $('#photosubmit').val() != "")
   $("#upload_form").submit();
});
```

Also, is the #upload_image click event, the right event to check if your input[type="file"] is filled?